# CodeIgniter works fine in localhost but when I passed to server only the index page works

Tags: php, codeigniter

*CodeIgniter* works fine in localhost but when I passed it to the server only the `index` page works.

I've tried changing the config.php by changing:

1. `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'PATH_INFO';` to `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'`
2. `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';`

But it still is not working.

`config.php` file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://s661658794.onlinehome.fr/admin';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

`

Comment: When routing the other page goes : Error 404 - Not found

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx on your production machine? And/or have you installed whatever variant of url rewriting is necessary?

Comment: The server is using apache I think.

Comment: The serve I got it had already installed php, apache and mysql on it. I have not installed any other component.

Comment: Are you trying to use urls like `/foo/bar/baz`? if so, make sure the apache plugin `mod_rewrite` is installed.

Comment: I've already tried adding :

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Sorry ^^ I'm new in stackoverflow I do not how to write comments properly

Comment: Undo the changes you made to your config file, that is not going to work. It could be so many reasons it is hard to offer advice. But have you set your base_url in the config file? If you are using mod rewrite to remove index.php from the urls then set 'index_page' to ''. (ie empty). Or, remove your .htaccess file and set 'index_page' to index.php to see if it works without mod_rewrite. Perhaps you could tell us what URL the links you have are trying to reach and what URL you were expecting. We might be able to offer more suggestions.

Comment: are you add the ht access file in your project to our write the index.php

Comment: Hey guys Thanks for help. I added a copy of the .htaccess file and a part of the config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed base_url() in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://demo.com/';
```

You Should add a new .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

You need to change database setting in database.php and undo all the above changes you done in your config.php